# Making a POJO Thread Safe

Tags: java, multithreading

Here's the class:

```
@NotThreadSafe
public class MutableInteger {
    private int value;
    public int get() { return value;}
    public void set(int value) { this.value = value;} 
}
```

Here's the post-condition that I have come up with: The value returned by `get()` is equal to the value value set by `set()` or 0.

It is easy to see that the above post-condition will not always hold true. Take two threads A and B for instance. Suppose A sets `value` to 5 and B sets it to 8 after that. Doing a `get()` in thread A would return 8. It should have returned 5. It is a simple race condition situation.

How can I make this class thread safe? In the book **Java: Concurrency in Practice**, the authors have guarded `value` and both the methods on the same object. I fail to understand how this helps at all with the race condition. First of all, `set()` is not a compound action. So, why do we need to synchronise it? And even after that, the race condition does not disappear. As soon as the lock is released once a thread exits from the `set()` method, another thread can aquire the lock and set a new value. Doing a `get()` in the initial thread will return the new value, breaching the post-condition.

(I understand the the author is guarding the `get()`) for visibility stuff. But I am not sure how it eliminates the race condition.

Comment: that, what you described, is not what is meant by "Thread Safe". If any Thread set a value to 8, any other Thread (or the same) should get 8 when calling `get()`! If you want a value per Thread you are looking for thread-local variables - see class `ThreadLocal`

Comment: Jeez man what a naive mistake. I forgot it was a single object. Embarrassing.

Comment: Re, "I fail to understand how this helps at all with the race condition." Making a class thread safe does not confer thread safety upon the code that uses it. If you write some method, `m()`, and every object that it touches is thread safe, and every method that it calls is thread safe, that _still_ is not enough to guarantee that method `m()` will be thread safe.

Comment: Example: A queue should promise that items come out in the same order that they went in, and a thread safe queue should keep that promise even when overlapping calls to its methods are made from many threads, but that promise does not help the caller to control the order in which items go in.  If you need item A to come out before item B comes out, then it's _your_ responsibility to _prove_ that no thread in your code will _start_ to put item B in to the queue until after some thread has _finished_ putting in item A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all, set() is not a compound action. So, why do we need to synchronise it?

You're not synchronising the `set()` in its own right, you're synchronising both the `get()` and `set()` methods against the same object (assuming you make both these methods synchronised.)

If you *didn't* do this, and the `value` variable isn't marked as volatile, then you can't guarantee that a thread will see the correct value because of per-thread caching. (Thread `a` could update it to 5, then thread `b` could still potentially see 8 *even after thread `a` has updated it.* That's what's meant by lack of thread safety in this context.)

You're correct that all reference assignments are atomic, so there's no worry about a corrupt reference in this scenario.

> And even after that, the race condition does not disappear. As soon as the lock is released once a thread exits from the set() method, another thread can aquire the lock and set a new value.

New threads setting new values (or new code setting new values) isn't an issue at all in terms of thread safety - that's designed, and expected. The issue is if the results are inconsistent, or specifically if multiple threads are able to concurrently view the object in an inconsistent state.